# Visual Studio Resource Editor corrupts rc files with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, resource-editor

Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 Resource Editor is able to correctly read and display .rc file in UTF-8 encoding if .rc file is saved without UTF-8 BOM.
The main requirements for it, .rc file must contain valid `#pragma code_page`.
Example:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_NEUD)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(65001)
```

But if you did some changes in textual resource and saves result back to .rc file, it will be corrupted:

- all `#pragma code_page(65001)` will be replaced by your default ANSI code page (e.g. `#pragma code_page(1252)`)
- all non ANSI symbol will be replaced by `?`.

Is there some way how to work with UTF-8 c++ resource in Visual Studio 2019\2022 Resource Editor without this bug.

P.S.:

- I don't use Unicode (UTF-16 LE) encoding due to problems in git with it.
- Using UTF-8 without BOM is single way how to compile UTF-8 .rc file in Visual Studio, see [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569).

Comment: And what did you do for `#pragma code_page` that were around special parts like includes? I guess this pragma have to match the included files encoding... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft knows about this bug and they decided not to fix it:

> Thank you very much for your feedback. We've decided to take no action on this feedback at the time.
> When working with Resource Compiler (.rc) source files, our suggestion has always been to use UTF-16 whenever resources contain strings that cannot be encoded as ASCII. Based on your replies, it looks like switching back to UTF-16 would unblock your experience with Resource Editor, with the caveat that GitHub won't treat .rc files as text.
> While eventually we want to support UTF-8 text encodings for .rc files, we currently do not have plans for this work; and for this reason we're closing this issue as Won't Fix.

See
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visualstudio-v1590-resource-editor-using-utf-8-bom/384705

Comment: That's strange, Raymond Chen himself suggest to switch rc files to utf-8 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569

Comment: The best advantage I see with `code_page(1200)` utf-16 is that more than being Unicode and 100% functional, it's also optional. Once converted, you can remove all the code_page entries. 1200 is the natural Visual encoding. Much better than 65001 utf-8. Plus, Visual will certainly remove them for you if you edit/save the resources.

Comment: @Sandburg, You will have problems in git with utff-16.

Comment: I will have more problems in Visual RC files with utf-8 (I tried). Until now, looks OK with utf-16LE in git.

Comment: @Sandburg, git treats utff-16 as binary file by default. it needs tuning to work with such files correctly.

Comment: This answer is wrong since in the very same Developer Community entry it is stated that the UTF-8 compatibility issues with the resource compiler are fixed with Windows SDK Version 10.0.20348.0 (rcdll.dll v10.0.19505.1001).